# backing up mysql database using php error

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, backup

Im trying to backup my database using this code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mjaudio");

define("BACKUP_PATH", "/mjaudio/uploads/");

$server_name   = "localhost";
$username      = "root";
$password      = "";
$database_name = "mjaudio";
$date_string   = date("Ymd");

$cmd = "mysqldump --routines -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} > " . BACKUP_PATH . "{$date_string}_{$database_name}.sql";

exec($cmd);

if (mysqli_query($conn, $cmd)) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'> ";
    echo "<strong>Backup Successfull</strong>";
    echo "</div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'> ";
    echo "<strong>Oops! Something went wrong!</strong>";
    echo "Error: " .$cmd."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
    echo "</div>";
}
```

but it gives me an error of:

```
Oops! Something went wrong!Error: mysqldump --routines -h localhost -u root -p mjaudio > /mjaudio/uploads/20180831_mjaudio.sql
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump --routines -h localhost -u root -p mjaudio > /mjaudio/uploads/20180831' at line 1
```

I've been trying to fix the query, but it doesn't seem to work. My current Xampp control panel is v3.2.2. Is there any problem in the versions?
How can I fix this?

Comment: $cmd is not a query...

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is you try to query your command line. Its not a SQL Statement. The rest of the code looks ok

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mjaudio");

define("BACKUP_PATH", "/mjaudio/uploads/");

$server_name   = "localhost";
$username      = "root";
$password      = "";
$database_name = "mjaudio";
$date_string   = date("Ymd");

$cmd = "mysqldump --routines -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} > " . BACKUP_PATH . "{$date_string}_{$database_name}.sql";

if (exec($cmd)) {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success'> ";
    echo "<strong>Backup Successfull</strong>";
    echo "</div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'> ";
    echo "<strong>Oops! Something went wrong!</strong>";
    echo "Error with: " .$cmd;
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: still the error is:

Oops! Something went wrong!Error: mysqldump --routines -h localhost -u root -p mjaudio > /mjaudio/uploads/20180831_mjaudio.sql
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump --routines -h localhost -u root -p mjaudio > /mjaudio/uploads/20180831' at line 1

Comment: i haven't seen the 'if' part. this is now the new error :
Oops! Something went wrong!Error: mysqldump --routines -h localhost -u root -p mjaudio > /mjaudio/uploads/20180831_mjaudio.sql

Comment: That means that the command returns false. can you check if the command is correct?

Comment: The command is correct. I tried using this format : 

mysqldump.exe –e –u[username] -p[password] -h[hostname] [database name] > C:\[filename].sql

still, the same error

Comment: This is not correct though
mysqldump --routines -h localhost -u root -p mjaudio > /mjaudio/uploads/20180831_mjaudio.sql
-p and password have to be without space, right?